# Using variables in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not much experienced with Oracle SQL and been trying to accomplish some task for which I intend to use

```
select count(*) from TABLE where date = (select trunc(sysdate -1 ) from dual)
```

The above query gives me the result for all the records with sysdate minus 1.  I want to automate it to handle the scenario of Sat and Sunday  and modify the query to something like below

```
select count(*) from TABLE where date = (select trunc(sysdate -@var ) from dual)
```

where @var = 2 if the query runs on Sunday and @var = 3 if the query is running on Monday

Comment: `trunc(sysdate -var )` will do - there is no need for a subquery. Can you describe what you mean by automating it though? Do you want a scheduled job that writes results to some table, or do you need an interactive report, or what?

Comment: The plan is put the script in an automated monitoring tool and run after a specific interval of time  ( say 10 Hrs ) and mail over  the results

Comment: Then the method for supplying variables will depend on the monitoring tool. What tool are you planning to use for this?

Answer (score 0):

`TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )` will truncate the date to the start of the ISO week - so midnight Monday. `TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )` will give the number of full days since the start of the ISO week (Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1, ... Sunday = 6) and you can just put that into a `CASE` statement:

```
select count(*)
from   your_table
where  date_col = TRUNC(SYSDATE) - CASE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
                                   WHEN 0 THEN 3 -- Monday
                                   WHEN 6 THEN 2 -- Sunday
                                          ELSE 1 -- Other days
                                   END
```